# If Chrome uses the same engine as Safari on iOS - will the adblockers work there too?

Tags: google-chrome, ios, adblock

iOS9 enabled add-blocking APIs - and there has been a slew of app-blocking applications released. This all appear to target Safari.

My understanding was that Chrome (on iOS) used the same engine as Safari when rendering pages.

My question is: **If Chrome uses the same engine as Safari on iOS - will the adblockers work there too?**

**Assumptions**

- on iOS, Chrome is using iOS WebKit not the Chrome WebKit.

Comment: On which information is the assumption based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same rendering engine under the hood (webkit), but different wrappers.
Chrome uses **UIWebView** which does **not** include Content Blockers API.

Due to performance, content blockers only work on new apple devices (hardware), and **not** on UIWebView nor WKWebView.

Comment: Could you clarify? My point was that

Comment: ...on iOS, Chrome is using iOS WebKit not the Chrome WebKit.

Comment: You're partially right.   Chrome on iOS uses the same webkit rendering engine,  as opposed to blink engine on the other platforms.    BUT - chrome uses  WKWebview,  which doesn't include the "content blocker" feature that Safari has.

Comment: @hawkeye I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Chrome on iOS still uses UIWebView https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423444

Comment: @Pier This doesn't invalidate this answer to the original question.. Please re-read the last paragraph of my original answer:  ".... and not on UIWebView or WKWebView"

Comment: You are stating that Chrome uses WKWebView which is incorrect.

Comment: @Pier Thanks for the link.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Pier It's now correct that Chrome uses WKWebView rather than UIWebView, and has been since Chrome 48 was released in the App Store at the end of January 2016.